# generar una secuencia numerica en un insert into from

Tags: sql-server

hola tengo una tabla que no tiene identity en su pk (ya que esta se genera a traves de un programa que llena la tabla).
debo ingresar registros desde otra tabla, pero me falta una funcion para generar este id.
tengo el siguiente insert para agregar los datos.

```
insert into movctble (movctbleid, MovctbleGlosa,MovctbleFecha,MovctbleEstado,MovctbleUserId,MovctbleUpdFhora,MovctbleClienteId) 
select liquidadescripcion, liquidafecha, liquidaestado, 0, liquidafecha, liquidacuenta from XAsientosFaltantes
```

pero me falta el primer campo.
como puedo generar este numero de forma automatica?
Saludos

Comment: Un autoincrementable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregarle al select la función `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY liquidafecha)`, eso te da una numeración secuencial, pero si lo que quieres es seguir la secuencia de la tabla, primero debes obtener el último valor de ese secuencial y se lo sumas al resultado de la función.

```
declare @variable numeric(18,0)
select @variable=max(SECUENCIAL) FROM XAsientosFaltantes
```

.
.
.

```
SELECT @variable+row_number() OVER (ORDER BY liquidafecha) FROM XAsientosFaltantes
```

Comment: gracias, funciono perfecto

Answer (score 1):

usa esto

```
insert into movctble (movctbleid, MovctbleGlosa,MovctbleFecha,MovctbleEstado,MovctbleUserId,MovctbleUpdFhora,MovctbleClienteId) 
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY liquidadescripcion ASC) AS Row, liquidadescripcion, liquidafecha, liquidaestado, 0, liquidafecha, liquidacuenta from XAsientosFaltantes
```